# How to calculate distance from detected face to image window

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am trying to get the exact distance from rectangle box and this arrow window. I have this code I detect my face but I am interested in calculating the total distance from `left,right,top,bottom` kindly help me.

[image]

Comment: I am new in this site so not exact idea how to write all detail in right way, My basic point is this when we detect any face like a rectangle box come up across face I wants to get the distance from rectangle to image window from top,bottom,left,right

Comment: I am using opencv python.

Comment: You should add more tags to help people find your question. Suggestions are 'python' and 'opencv', assuming the latter is a tag. I submitted an edit to that effect.